# URL rewriting in joomla

Tags: joomla

I need to rewrite url in joomla. But the url should not be showing "index.php" and no numbers (0-9) as well.

1st condition:
The url cannot be " http://www.abc.com/index.php/components/article" rather than it should be "http://www.abc.com/components/article".

2nd condition:
the url cannot be "http://www.abc.com/components/article/9" where it contains 9 number .

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla comes with htaccess.txt, and the option to rewrite urls. So you have to first change the htaccess.txt file to .htaccess on the server, then login and in the configuration settings change SEF to on, and use .htaccess to on.

Answer (score 1):

In support of the answers from [gnomeontherun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321553/gnomeontherun) and [Hennie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314131/hennie).  You have some control over how the url is made up by joomla, through the menu structure and the alias for the each menu.

Sometimes it's worth creating menu items even if you don't show them on a menu on your site.

e.g.
Menu structure:

```
Home
-Latest News *(Could be a category blog view)*
--News article 1 *(Link to article but this level need not be shown on menu)*
--News article 2 *(Link to article but this level need not be shown on menu)*
```

url should look like:

```
/latest-news    *(for the blog view)*
/latest-news/news-article-1   *(for the article view)*
```

If there is no menu item which relates to an article, Joomla makes up the url itself using category+id/article-alias+id etc.  If it does find a menu item, it will use the structure of the menu instead.

Joomla uses the alias of the menus for the actual content:

i.e. `menu-alias-level1/menu-alias-level2/news-article-1`

Using this method from the beginning will allow you to keep your urls consistent whether they are accessed through the blog page route or directly.  This will help with your SEO.

Of course it can be a pain to create a menu item for every article but I know some Joomla guys who swear by it and will do it even for thousands of pages...

Answer (score 0):

for the index part ...
Perhaps this will work for you too
`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.yourdomain.com/ [R=301,L]`

or

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the 'index.php':

1. Rename the htaccess.txt file to .htaccess
2. In the backend, turn on SEF URLs and URL rewrite

Joomla will then show your article using something like "http://www.example.com/category/article/9", unless you assign a menu item to that article. There is no need to show that menu, so you can create new menu, call it 'hidden' (or any other valid name) and do not publish the module.

A more comfortable option is to use one of the many SEF components, which make it much easier to manage the URLs. Most if them additionally provide meta data control.