# joomla script to change the URL for the site as required

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, router

Is there any joomla 2.5 script to change the URL for the site as required.

`http://www.test.com/index.php?com_test`

to

`http://www.test.com/test.html`

without any extension.

If possible, how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing your own extension you need to create your own router. Here is a good starting point http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component also have a look how other extensions did it (com_contact).

Answer (score 1):

I think your question could be answered in this question:
[URL rewriting in joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620939/url-rewriting-in-joomla)

Joomla has built in ability to rewrite the urls but you need to activate this:

In Global configuration there area a couple of settings for url rewrite and then you need to rename the htaccess.txt file in the root folder of your Joomla installation to htaccess.